# Formatting help: vertical rule, headers

Tags: formatting

I am trying to reproduce the [famous employee handbook](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.valvesoftware.com%2Fcompany%2FValve_Handbook_LowRes.pdf&ei=OT17U-TJEcOvyASQm4GwDg&usg=AFQjCNGmWgIlQd82l9JBQq0n2a6u61s9KA&bvm=bv.67229260,d.aWw) from Valve. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm making progress, but am stumped on three issues. 1) How to make my vertical line separating pages continue through the header and footer. 2) When I create a chapter, the pagination is treated as one page, rather than two, as I have it through the rest of the document. 3) I'd like to reproduce the running headers, but am experiencing difficulty there too. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color, graphicx}



%%%%%%%%%% Experiments %%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{dashrule}

%%%%%%% Wallpaper

\usepackage{wallpaper}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214,82,10}
%\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{202, 64, 28}
\setromanfont{Libre Baskerville} 
\setsansfont{Andada} 
\setmonofont{Andada} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.4}
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn, left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\thepage}}
\rfoot{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\number\numexpr\value{page}+1}\stepcounter{page}}
\title{Fake Title}
\author{Larry Tate}
\date{}

%%%%%Page Boxes%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}


\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}


\begin{document}


\CenterWallPaper{.95}{background}

\chapter*{Chapter One}


\section*{\color{Ahrenge}The First Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}

Hello World! This is a block quote within the text sample. This is quite fake. Why are you still reading?

\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]

%\noindent\hdashrule[0.5ex]{10.5cm}{1.4pt}{2.5mm}

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=brown!27]
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

%\noindent\hdashrule[0.5ex]{10.5cm}{1.4pt}{2.5mm}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section*{\color{Ahrenge} The Second Section}
\lipsum[1-2]


\section*{\color{Ahrenge}This is a Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section*{\color{Ahrenge} The Next Section}


\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Here is the background image file.[image]

Comment: I think it's better to produce the book as a normal one, and once finished compound two pages over your background with `pdfpages`. Another option would be to break your background into two fragments an use corresponding one for every page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to produce a lanscaped two pages format I'd suggest to produce a book and once it's finished use `pdfpages` or any other package to place to pages over a background image.

Next code shows how to use `pdfpages` and `background` pacakges to create the final result. Original file (`179275.pdf`) was created with `\blinddocument` from (`blindtext` package).

You'll have to adjust your text and background image. `background` package documentation explains how to use different background images for even and odd pages. This could be another solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{mwe}

\backgroundsetup{%
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
      opacity=0.1,
    contents={%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a4}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,landscape,frame]{179275}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some ideas. However, using the opacity for the image really degrades the readability of the text embedded in the .pdf.

Comment: Thanks, Ignasi. I see what you are trying to do there. However, using the opacity/transparency really degrades the quality of the typeface on the .pdf. Hm...

Comment: @LarryTate: What happens with this degradation when using `wallpaper`? If wallpaper works better, use it. Divide (or clip) your background and use it as a background for a normal book. After that you can compound two pages view with `pdfpages`.